# How could they be hit twice by debris?

Tags: gravity

In the movie [*Gravity*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1454468/) the two astronauts (Bullock and Clooney) are hit *twice* by the fast moving debris that bring havoc to their locations. I think this is a bad scientific mistake in the movie plot.

Indeed, different objects cannot travel the *same* orbit at different speeds. The shape of the orbit is defined by the total energy which depends essentially on velocity. So, objects that happen to be at the same point with different velocities will follow different orbits.

It is true that orbits are closed (in classical mechanics, not counting disturbing effects) so that an object will go over and over again through the same points, and the speedier objects will be again at the point where it met the slower one, but in the meantime the slower has also moved and the two won't pass through the meeting point at the same time again.

Any further meeting would occur only after a certain number of orbits, which makes way more than the mere 90 minutes claimed in the movie.

Is there a scientifically sound explanation for this?

Comment: *"What do you think"* - I think it is true that gravity was [scientifically inaccurate quite often in its details](http://www.vulture.com/2013/10/astronaut-fact-checks-gravity.html). So what? Is there an actual question asked here?

Comment: This would be a better fit for http://scifi.stackexchange.com/ or for the 'hard science' side of it, http://space.stackexchange.com/.  Most of the pieces would be in an elliptical orbit, and would quickly spread into a broad field, so it is quite possible the astronauts would be hit twice.  I've not seen the movie, but had heard it does not let science get in the way of a good story.

Comment: The director himself has admitted that the orbital mechanics in his movie are wrong. Early drafts of the movie were more faithful to reality, but they turned out too boring, so to speed things up scientific inaccuracy was introduced.

Comment: I think this questions would be best answered on [Sci-fi](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/?as=1) or [Space SE](http://space.stackexchange.com/?as=1). Migration would do so much good to it.

Comment: Waiting on Moderator comment for migration.

Comment: Its absolutely disheartening to see such a well framed question lay idle and not garner the attention it should. @Andrea Mori: I urge you to move this question to one of the above mentioned sites. And ya, don't forget to provide us with a link to it! :) Cheers!

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher: after reading the link provided by Christian in the first comment I got so convinced that Gravity is so ridden with scientific inaccuracies that I kind of lost interest in having a discussion on this topic :)

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher Cross-posting questions on SE is not a good idea.  I could move this to space.se in a flash but its considered rude to do so without a blessing from a moderator of that site.